# Python: list filtering using list comprehension

Tags: python, filter, list-comprehension

I have a sorted list of values i need to filter such that the only values returned are not the same as the value to its left.

For example mylist=[1,2,2,3,3,3,3,6,7,9,9,11] would return [1,2,3,6,7,9,11].

I've done this task using for and if loops but wondering if there is not a more elegant solution using list comprehensions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a **sorted** list, that is by definition the same thing as `list(set(mylist))`, which just uniquifies your list.

But, code golfing a bit, since you asked for a list-comp, there's the charming:

```
seen = set()

[x for x in mylist if x not in seen and not seen.add(x)]
Out[3]: [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 11]
```

Or:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

[tup[0] for tup in zip_longest(mylist,mylist[1:]) if len(set(tup)) == 2]
Out[11]: [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 11]
```

The latter of which works with your requirement on non-sorted lists as well.

As you can see, both of these are less readable than `list(set(mylist))`, which should be preferred if you know that your input lists will always be sorted.

Comment: Thanks @roippi.  Can you explain the mechanics behind solution 1 a bit?  Having a little trouble understanding how the "and not seen.add(x)" is filtering the list.

Comment: @user2957824 that's the code golf-ish part.  `set.add` does not return anything, so that part is equivalent to `and not None` which is always true.  It also adds `x` to the `set`, so the second time around `x in seen` is `True` and it gets filtered out.

Comment: The value of this answer for me is in showing the basic syntax of a list-comprehension.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a way to do it with list comprehension, but a better way to do it would be:

```
mylist=[1,2,2,3,3,3,3,6,7,9,9,11]
uniqueList = list(set(mylist))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
>>> m=set( mylist)
>>> m
set([1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 11])
```